# How to use the simpler regex check that chrome extension uses for URLs?

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to limit the websites that my chrome extension runs on (based on user settings so this can't be set in the manifest.json) but I'd like the regex to be easy for users to input themselves. The regex that I am looking for is actually the same kind that the chrome extension is looking for in it's manifest file for the URLs the extension will run on.

For example, https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns

stackoverflow.com/*

If I have that is an input to the options page. How can I get javascript to use this kind of regex validation instead of the more formal regex (that includes .?*[]|) ?

If I can use that kind of regex check I will pull the tab.url and the urls from user options, and validate to check if the extension needs to run on the current page or not.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to analyze the text yourself or simply convert the string to RE2 (see below):

Assuming `var url = new URL(url_text)` (in the actual code this won't work because protocol may be `*://` so you'll have to split the parts with regexp), here's a few examples of the logic:

- if `url.pathname` contains one `*` at the end use `urlPrefix` of [the event filter](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events#method-Event-addRules#type-UrlFilter) and `hostEquals`
- if `url.pathname` is `"/"` and `url.hostname` has `*` at the end use `hostPrefix`
- ..............

This is a simple example that doesn't even check for multiple `*` in the input text, but in the working code don't forget to also parse and provide `schemes` parameter as well as `ports` and of course the various cases of `*` placement will produce different set of matching rules.

If none if the simple string event filters were applicable or you're not concerned with the performance (not sure the penalty is significant and can be measured at all though) then escape the string for Chrome's RE2 matching and use `urlMatches` or `originAndPathMatches`:

```
url_text.replace(/[{}()\[\]\\.+?^$|]/g, "\\$&").replace(/\*/g, ".*?")
```